# FineUploader allowedExtensions use an array?

Tags: javascript, configuration, fine-uploader

I'm using FineUploader v3.8, and have successfully gotten it up and running.  At this point, I'm listing the available file types to the user in HTML, and there's a reference to these in the configuration.  I wanted to have only one place where the extensions are listed so there's no duplication, and it can be easily changed.

I tried something like this:

`var allowedExtensions = new Array('jpg', 'gif', 'png');`

`var allowedExtensions = "'jpg', 'gif', 'png'";`

And then within 'validation:' I used something like this:

`allowedExtensions: [allowedExtensions],`

This doesn't work, and I get an invalid file type messagebox for any/all file types.
Is there a way I could easily utilize the array variable in the javascript of the control configuration?  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the 1st and 3rd snippet, you're actually creating an `Array` containing another `Array`

It probably just needs either an [array literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Array_literals) (`[...]`) or `new Array(...)` rather then both.

```
var allowedExtensions = ['jpg', 'gif', 'png'];
```

```
allowedExtensions: allowedExtensions, // no extra brackets
```